# Laravel does not accept file while post

Tags: laravel

I am uploading file from front end (React or Postman) to Laravel API. I try to print all the parameters received from front end as below. I have set the `Content-Type : multipart/form-data` in both UI and postman.

```
dd( $request->all() );
```

File value is always empty. Is there any I am missing. Attached is the postman sample. Seems like some configuration issue at Laravel API. Unable to find that.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which version of Laravel you're running but the `$request` class has a built-in method called `file` in which you pass the name. So, maybe this works `dd( $request->file('files') )`.

Here's the documentation link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

Comment: Thanks. How I forgot this